# chrome search in page: accented characters

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromium, special-characters

Searching text inside a webpage (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>) for an accented character, for instance `è`, chromium finds all occurrences of `è`, `é` and `e`.

Similarly, searching `e` finds `è` and `é` as well.

While it is an awesome function, is there an option, escape sequence or anything else to make chrome just find the typed character?

Comment: Good question. The behavior is not consistent. On my Chrome, “ä” is treated as distinct from “a” (which is good for me, since these are quite distinct letters in Finnish, but it appears to be inconsistent with the “é” issue).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I wouldn't go that far. `ä` and `a` are different letters, `é` is just an `e` with an acute accent.

Comment: well, `ä` is just an `a` with a dieresis/umlaut, or not? it would be interesting how this is treated in mysql collations

Comment: In German (at least), `ä`, `ö` and `ü` are different (modern) ways of writing `ae`, `oe` and `ue`. The pronunciation of `ü` and `u`, for example, is entirely different.

Comment: @Jukka. It's interesting: in some languages accented letters are counted as different letters, while in others they're just variants.

Comment: My local is UK English and it treats ä as a. Probably it's to do with the language settings. I need search for non-English texts, and this behaviour is kinda ruining it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, this behavior can't be disabled. You could, however, use a text search extension that behaves differently.

[Type-ahead-find](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpecbmjeidppdiampimghndkikcmoadk), for example, only finds exact matches.

Comment: +1. It makes me remember it was the default find behavior of a browser  I had used for some time maybe 10 years ago on fedora (was it galeon?).

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately this has been a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71741) for at least a year and a half, but has not (yet?) been addressed. You can star the issue for updates.

Comment: Still a bug. :( Try Ctrl+F for "é" on [a table of common character sets](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unicode/cstab.html#Latin-1)! Ugh...

Comment: I got around this (and many, many other problems) a couple of years ago by abandoning Chrome and switching to Firefox. Life has been so much better since then.

Comment: Funny, I'm using Chrome because I'd given up on Firefox.